# Process an xml db export by row

Tags: python, xml

Let's take the StackOverflow public export of Tags, which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="303362" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="1038358" ExcerptPostId="3673183" WikiPostId="3673182" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="javascript" Count="2130783" ExcerptPostId="3624960" WikiPostId="3607052" />
  ...
```

Let's assume that this object wouldn't fit in memory, but since it's line-separated I think it'd be OK to process without doing too much trickery. What might be a good approach to process a file like this? My thought was just to process it by row, building faking the xml structure, something like:

```
for line in file:
    node = etree.fromstring('<x>%s</x>' % line).find('row')
    ...
```

Is this a common approach for handling xml that is "row-oriented" that is too big to fit in memory? I see this commonly with DB exports (actually i think the db client I use does that format, though I never use xml-exports from a db).

Comment: I would go with SAX. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html

Comment: @balderman thanks, I think that's probably the proper way, though a bit of overhead with registering the events and such. Want to show a basic example for the above and I'll award the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAX is a abbreviation of Simple API to XML and provides a very fast and lightweight access to XML data. In contrast to DOM, which reads the whole XML document and creates a in-memory tree representation from it, SAX gives the program available information immediately after they are read from the document during parsing. The workflow is a follows - the parser reads the document and each time it finds a distinct type of XML data, such as start of an element, end of an element, processing instruction, etc. it passes the information to the so called handler

See a concrete example here: http://python.zirael.org/e-sax1.html